# TouchXML, get text value of node objective-c

Tags: objective-c, touchxml

I've looked all over the web but just can't figure out how to get the text from a node in Objective-C. I'm using TouchXML and I am getting my node list. I want the title text from a node, but instead I get a node object. My code is:

```
resultNodes = [xmlParser nodesForXPath:@"SearchResults/SearchResult" error:&err];

for (CXMLElement *resultElement in resultNodes) {
        
NSString *value = [resultElement elementsForName:@"Title"];
}
```

If I log the value to the console I get:

```
<CXMLElement 0x3994b10 [0x39732a0] Title <Title HtmlEncoded="true">test question</Title>>
```

I want the text, i.e `test question` instead. I am banging my head against a brick wall here.

Answer (score 4):

Since there should atleast one element in "resultElement" for the given value"Title", you can probably access it by adding following line of code:

```
   NSString *value = [[[resultElement  elementsForName:@"Title"] objectAtIndex:0] stringValue];
```

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
NSString *value = [[resultElement elementsForName:@"Title"] getStringValue];
```